# Mod_rewrite Redirect Specific IP to page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been trying to get my website to redirect a specific IP to a particular page.

Using the Following in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^138\.91\.49\.132$
RewriteRule .* http://www.anothersite.com/mypage.html [R=302,L]
```

The IP 138.91.49.132 should be redirected. Nothing gets redirected.

When I use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^138\.91\.49\.132$
RewriteRule .* http://www.anothersite.com/mypage.html [R=302,L]
```

Everything except 138.91.49.132 should be redirected. Everything gets redirected.

What exactly is going on here as it is getting me very frustrated... am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working by using the HTTP:CF-CONNECTING-IP as it seems Cloudflare CDN was disrupting the use of RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-CONNECTING-IP} ^(212\.219\.11\.6)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://lol.awebsite.co.uk [R=301,L]
```

Thank you anubhava for getting me to this stage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `REMOTE_ADDR` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^138\.91\.49\.132$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.anothersite.com/mypage.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to give any effect... When loading my site from the system with that IP it is still not redirecting..

Comment: Make sure this is your **very fist** rule and .htaccess is working.

Comment: I know the htaccess works as I can get the following to work

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

When I remove that and replace it with the code you supplied. it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok then then are you sure this IP is indeed what Apache sees? (check Apache access.log)

Comment: I'm very much afraid it is the correct ip as per the logs.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not it is the browsers I am using causing issues.... Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work. In fact, IE doesn't even redirect, it just breaks saying can't find my website. Chrome Finds my website perfectly fine and does not redirect.

Comment: Since it is 301 you need to completely clear your browser cache or use a new browser to test.

Comment: I'm actually starting to think the Condition just isn't working for some reason... As soon as I apply a RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} or RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} condition to my previously meantioned working redirect. It breaks.

Comment: Infact, could cloudflare cdn affect this in any way? Never mind... Already established the correct ip has is being detected,.

Comment: ok comment this rule and then create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://subdomain.domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` value.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way of using HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP as a condition rule, because that displays fine.

Comment: Infact, I belive I have solved the issue now by using RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} ^(138\.91\.49\.132)

Comment: Which means that you were getting this IP from a reverse proxy.